# Hugging face classifier speed (list comprehension)

Tags: list, performance, optimization, huggingface-transformers

Hope you are doing well!

I am trying to use the transfomers library of huggingface.
I want to optimize the speed

Screen of speed test using list comprehension:
[image: 1]
The text in the list is around 500 characters each.

I don't understand why this

```
[classifier(review, labels,
       multi_label=True) for review in list]
```

is faster than

```
classifier(list, labels, multi_label=True)
```

Do you have any idea why it does this?

Thank you !

Comment: Isn't it that the reviews have very different lengths? In that case, you could lose a lot of time on padding to the maximum length. Also, pasting code and outputs as images is not a good practice on SO.

Comment: Thanks ! Noted for the pasting code and outputs